# How do I change SHOP BY text in left sidebar Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, layered-navigation, filter

How to change the text **SHOP BY** from left sidebar at category page in Magento?

I want to change this text SHOP BY to another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution for my own question.

To get this Please open this path:

**Magento 1 :**

```
app/design/frontend/default/YOURTHEME/template/catalog/layer/view.phtml
```

Change the class name "block-title" to something else.

**Magento 2x:**

```
vendor/magento/module-layered-navigation/view/frontend/templates/layer/view.phtml
```

Copy to Theme Path

```
app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/Magento_LayeredNavigation/templates/layer/view.phtml
```

Change Code:

```
div class="block-title filter-title">
            <strong><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Shop By New Text Here..')) ?></strong>
        </div>
```

Comment: Asked the question and next minute answering.OMG

Comment: Actually, Brother. I am searching for this from last two days. I got the answer today. I thought, someone is also struggling with this. So i posted this.

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara brother in this community every one is there to help.and like to establish the quality of the forum. That's why +1 and -1.not for personal issues.thanks for the good heart to share your knowledge :)

Comment: when i want to change text from shop by to shop by category, i found this. thank you. i upvoted this

Comment: Any chance you could kindly update your answer to include Magento 2.2.x. Thank you.

Comment: @MohammedJoraid, updated please check once

Comment: Thank you Taja for your answer. I did something similar and changed the language file.

Answer (score 1):

More than that if you want to change anything in Magento 
just go to *System -> Configuration -> Advance -> Developer* then select your store view from right sidebar in a Magento admin and **enable Template Path Hints** then follow the path in frontend and edit in the particular file whatever you want

Comment: This path may help to get the solutions like above question. i upvoted this.

Comment: For the sake of accessibility, I will leave this line here. In my case, most likely I will have a terminal session opened rather than the Admin page. 

You man also enable **Template Path Hints** using CLI: 

**To enable:** `php bin/magento dev:template-hints:enable `

**To disable:** `php bin/magento dev:template-hints:disable `